# django strip/remove/clear value

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.6.7 & python 2.7.

I am trying to clear the data in a field if it fits a condition before the value is submitted to the database.

I had been using strip, but this no longer works. After searching the django docs I cannot find a solution.

Here is my code in my forms.py file, where strip() does not work:

```
        if atype_config.LocalityDisplay:
            def clean_address_locality(self):
                value = self.cleaned_data['address_locality']
                return value.strip()
```

Comment: `strip` is string function, not related to django. Will you please give example of `value.strip()` not working. What is value and what you expect from this.

Comment: Also, you're just defining the function inside the if clause, which is strange in itself, and never executing it.

Comment: Lafada, the data string in value.strip() should be deleted, so that null is being returned by value.strip().

Comment: limelights, sorry, that was a typo I left in when I was trying different solutions. I have deleted the not.

Comment: Why don't you just return `None` inside of that function then? `strip()` has never returned `None` if a value in the string is present.

Comment: Do you mean:             if atype_config.LocalityDisplay:
                def clean_address_locality(self):
                    value = self.cleaned_data['address_locality']
                    return None

Comment: Yeah, if that's what you really want to do. But I'm guessing that you're using the form data to create an instance so you would have to update the `cleaned_data` field as well.

Comment: I have just tried, but I cannot get it working. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: `del self.cleaned_data['address_locality']` if you want remove it from form before save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not to user strip. Use pop() instead.

Here is the code:

```
if not atype_config.LocalityDisplay:
    self.cleaned_data.pop('address_locality', None)
```

I hope that this helps someone.