# django namedtuple not returning value

Tags: python, django, namedtuple

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out why the following codes does not properly work. I have searched SO, Python docs & Google and read the django docs, but I still cannot work out why it does not work.

Basically, I have a named tuple that stores the required fields data. I then want to call on the named tuple to clear data from the form before the entry is saved/updated to the database.

For example, when the address_type selected by the user is 6, then the LocalityDisplay is False. Then in the validation of the form, the **if atype_config.LocalityDisplay == False:** should be tripped and the value in the address_locality should be removed, meaning that no vaule should be saved to the database for the **address_locality**. I have used **return value.strip()** else where in my forms.py and it works well.

I am unsure if I have made a fundamental error in coding the named tuple causing the named tuple not to be indexed correctly or if I have coded the **if atype_config.LocalityDisplay == False:** condition incorrectly or made some other error I cannot see.

There is no error displayed, the **if atype_config.LocalityDisplay == False:** appears no to be tripped/reached.

Here is my code:

**forms.py**

```
from collections import namedtuple

RequiredFields = namedtuple('RequiredFields', ['LocalityDisplay', 'LocalityRequired', 'RegionDisplay', 'RegionRequired', 'PostcodeDisplay', 'PostcodeRequired'])

........... (do some stuff here)

class AddressDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

........... (do some stuff here)

REQUIRED_FIELDS = {
    0: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=False),
    1: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=False, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=True, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    2: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=False, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    3: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=False, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    4: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=False, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    5: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=True, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    6: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=False, LocalityRequired=False, RegionDisplay=True, RegionRequired=True, PostcodeDisplay=True, PostcodeRequired=True),
    ........... (culled for brevity)
    285: RequiredFields(LocalityDisplay=True, LocalityRequired=True, RegionDisplay=False, RegionRequired=False, PostcodeDisplay=False, PostcodeRequired=False)
}

........... (do some stuff here)

cd_addf = super(AddressDetailsForm, self).clean()
    address_type = cd_addf.get('address_country_style_type', None)
    if address_type is None:
        # Prior validation will spot this
        pass
    elif address_type == 0:
        self._errors['address_country_style_type'] = self.error_class([_("You must select an Address Format.")])
    else:
        atype_config = REQUIRED_FIELDS[address_type]

        ........... (do some stuff here)

        if atype_config.LocalityDisplay == False:
            def clean_address_locality(self):
                value = self.cleaned_data['address_locality']
                return value.strip()

        ........... (do some stuff here)

    return cd_addf
```

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623810/django-strip-remove-clear-value), but did not resolve the issue, so I am not sure what is the cause of the code not working.

Comment: Are you sure ```address_type``` isn't ```None``` or ```0```?

Comment: schillingt, I looked at that by removing the if else condition and having only the if atype_config.LocalityDisplay == False: condition. The issue still occurred.

Comment: Did you try adding some logging to see where the execution goes not as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with your namedtuple. If you'd add some logging as suggested in the comment, you'd have been able to see that. The problems are entirely within that if statement, where the code makes no sense at all.

Firstly, as explained at length in your other question, `strip` doesn't do what you appear to think it does. It returns the value with whitespace stripped off the end. If you want your clean function to return None, then just return None, don't use strip.

Secondly, and far more significant, it is completely pointless to define a function inside an if statement inside another method. Django can't know anything about your new method, you can't call a function defined inside another function from outside, and even if you could Django has already finished with the `clean_fieldname` functions by the time it calls the main `clean` method.

But all that is pointless in any case; you have access to the `cleaned_data` dictionary in the `clean` method already, so why not simply remove the element there?

```
if not atype_config.LocalityDisplay:
    self.cleaned_data.pop('address_locality', None)
```